# Create the equivilent of a SELECT SUM() GROUP BY query in PHP code on variables/arrays?

Tags: php, arrays

I need to process a dynamic amount of incoming data (from $_POST, not a DB) that looks something like this:

```
ID | VALUE 
10000 | 15.50
10000 | 25.00
11000 | 40.25
12000 | 20.25
11000 | 10.50
```

And produce an multidimensional array that sums and groups everything to end up looking like this:

```
array(
    0 => array ('id'=>10000, 'value'=>40.50),
    1 => array ('id'=>11000, 'value'=>50.75),
    2 => array ('id'=>12000, 'value'=>20.25)
)
```

So basically the SQL statement:

```
SELECT id, SUM(value) FROM [table] GROUP BY id;
```

I'm currently trying to brute force a solution and should get there eventually, but I'm wondering if there's an 'elegant' way to do this in PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is: Use an associative array with the ID values as keys.

Start by initializing an empty array:

```
$totals = array ();
```

Then as you read values in, keep a running total for each ID in the array:

```
for (...) {  // Read in data
    if (!array_key_exists($id, $totals))
        $totals[$id] = $value;
    else
        $totals[$id] += $value;
}
```

At the end of input, `$totals` holds the total for each ID, which you can quickly output:

```
echo 'ID | VALUE' . PHP_EOL;
foreach ($totals as $id => $total)
    echo $id . ' | ' . $total . PHP_EOL;
```

Or convert to an indexed array, as in your question:

```
$indexed_totals = array ();
foreach ($totals as $id => $total)
    $indexed_totals[] = array ($id, $total);
```

Comment: @Randy Great! Please mark my answer as accepted then so I can receive credit for it. And welcome to Stack Overflow!